# How to clear LLDB console

Tags: debugging, terminal, console, lldb

How do I clear the console screen in an LLDB session terminal?   I know in GDB this is done with `shell clear`
(`Ctrl+L` does not work for my case since I am running my LLDB session in VSCode debug console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the gdb case, `shell clear` is spawning a sub shell and calling that shell's `clear` command.  Because the shell is sharing the same terminal with gdb, this acts to clear the terminal.

In the case of VSCode, lldb isn't directly connected to a terminal, it's just feeding text to VSCode through a socket.  So it has no influence over the window VSCode chooses to display the text in.  The VSCode-lldb interface would have to have a "clear your console" primitive for it to work in cases like this.  That does not exist on the lldb side.  I don't know whether it exists on the VSCode side.

Comment: Is there an equivalent to `shell clear` in `lldb` when run from the terminal and not VSCode?

Comment: `platform shell` is lldb's equivalent to the gdb `shell` command.  But when lldb makes a sub-shell it does NOT share the terminal with the sub-shell, so `clear` thinks it is running on a dumb terminal, which it doesn't know how to clear.  If you are using the macOS Terminal.app, however, Cmd-K clears the console buffer.  Maybe that's why nobody's ever tried `platform shell clear`.